# Json.Serializer wont serialize + sign

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I have this code

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestContactNew()
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All),
            WriteIndented = true
        };
        string aplus = "A+";
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(aplus, options).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", aplus, json);
    }
```

It outputs

A+ "A\u002B"

When I expect

A+ "A+"

What I'm doing wrong?

I uploaded the code here https://github.com/dhilst/csharp-test3

To run on console I use this `dotnet test --logger:"console;verbosity=detailed"`

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [dotnet core System.Text.Json unescape unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58003293/3744182), please check.

Comment: [`System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Encodings_Web_JavaScriptEncoder_UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping) from the above answer does work, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/O19XWo.  Looks like a duplicate.

Comment: For some discussion about why Microsoft did this see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35281 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#minimal-character-escaping

Comment: What are the security concerns about plus sign? It is considered HTML or something like that? I can't find anything about what characters would be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the references, it seems that this is the expected behavior and it's about some security concerns, but I can't find what

Comment: I think the security concerns arise when the JSON is embedded in HTML or a `<script>` element rather than sent standalone as part of a `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` payload.  See the Caution under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialize-all-characters for Microsoft's explanation.  Anyway, for those of us who don't want the extra escaping there's a documented way to avoid it.

Comment: I found this: [Security benefits of encoding HTML special characters in JSON responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13236415/3744182).

Comment: Thanks @dbc, in fact if there is a security concert and MS take care of this fore me I would like to use the safer option. Thanks for your explanation, I never thought about this, lots of JSON fields are simply rendered in HTML, and this may be an XSS attack vector, thanks again!